# Powerpoint for Mac - can't save current page as PDF

Tags: pdf, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a powerpoint file containing a few hundred slides, and want to save one specific slide as a PDF. I choose "Save AS", Format: PDF, and in Options I select "Save current Slide". However it always saves the whole presentation. Does anyone know why, or have a simple workaround? (note: this works fine in Windows)

Comment: never tried it, but how about Print... then save as PDF ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `File > Print >` set From: / To: to the one page you want then select PDF in the bottom left corner and choose whatever makes sense for you -- I like to open it right into Preview to verify it's what I want.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've verified that it works, although the resulting file size is twice as big as the "normal" way I always did this from my PC. This must be a pure bug, right? Any other alternative workarounds?

Comment: That's crazy! I do see a difference of 21KB & 20KB, but that's not enough for me to care. Worst case, I recommend copy/pasting just that slide into a new deck and then saving it. I've used that workaround many times.